# CodeIgniter Exec Controller through CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, exec, command-line-interface

I'm trying to invoque a CodeIgniter controller through CLI, using an exec command, in order to  send emails without waiting for the server reply.

However, this is simply not working and I don't really understand why.

The process starts in **user controller** with a library call

```
$this->load->library('Mailer');
...
$this->mailer->send_user_email($email,$token);
```

The `$email` is sent with a `%20` replacing the `@` so CI could accept it as valid URL

Then in **Mailer** Library the code is as follows

```
chdir('/var/www/projectroot');
$command='php index.php mailing send_email '.$mail.' '.$token.' > output.txt 2> error.txt &';
exec($command);
```

Then in **mailing controller** the mail should be sent

```
 $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(
   ....

  echo $mailer->send($message);
```

I've tested calling this controller directly in the server command line, and it worked perfectly. Also, the string produced within the `$command` variable is correct and works also if I manually feed it to the CLI.

There's also no kind of output given to the output.txt file neither to error.txt

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You should in any case use `escapeshellarg($mail)` and `escapeshellarg($token)` to prevent from shell command injection. Maybe this will fix the error as well.

Comment: Nicelly pointed, but, nope, it didn't solve anything

Comment: How are you calling the controller? from command line or browser?

Comment: Which one? Users through HTTP request and mailing through CLI

Comment: remove the `2> ...` error redirection. What do you see?

Comment: @hek2mgl - Nothing new happened. Still no output file :(

Comment: Try `passthru($command)` .. What does it say now?

Comment: @hek2mgl Strange... still no output file

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in index.php

Comment: @hek2mgl Ok, so I've sorted out, the problem was in the `> output.txt` part, so I removed it and it worked. Why is this happening?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29198/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-joao-dias)

Comment: you can use cronjob right.........

Comment: @Venkat A cronjob doesn't send the email imediately and is a bit of an overkill so I think?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be useful to check is that does your code use directly, or indirectly by system functions, $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’], which doesn't exist in CLI mode. I had bit similar problems with CLI myself.

You could check if this is a problem by modifying core/Input.php (line 351 in 2.1.3) to:

```
    if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $this->ip_address = '0.0.0.0';
```